# PHP Laravel Doctrine\DBAL\PDOException SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: php, laravel

I have been trying to set up PHP Laravel 5.7.0 by installing and configuring Homestead and Vagrant with the VirtualBox plugin on Windows 8.1. I have been trying to make "php artisan migrate" work for a long time now but I keep getting this error:

> PHP Laravel Doctrine\DBAL\PDOException SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No
>   connection could be made because the target machine actively refused
>   it

Or another error message like "Connection attempt refused"

Can anyone help me figure out what I have been doing wrong in my configuration?

~/Homestead/Homestead.yaml

```
--- 
authorize: ~/.ssh/homestead_rsa.pub
cpus: 1
databases: 
  - homestead
folders: 
  - 
    map: "C:\\reggie\\code\\salvo"
    to: /home/vagrant/Code
ip: "192.168.10.10"
keys: 
  - ~/.ssh/homestead_rsa
memory: 2048
provider: virtualbox
sites: 
  - 
    map: homestead.test
    to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public
variables: 
  - 
    key: APP_ENV
    value: local
```

/c/reggie/code/salvo/.env

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:9REWE8zTJepml2KPA0icpkJoond+Gln0mMKwYs7/lrQ=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

/c/reggie/code/salvo/config/database.php

```
return [

    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

    'connections' => [

        ...

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'homestead' == gethostname() ? 
                      'localhost' : '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'homestead'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'homestead'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'secret'),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

Please let me know if I missed any pertinent detail. Thank you!

Comment: is database username and password is correct ?

Comment: Check if the phpMyAdmin works on the same IP with username and password you provided.

Comment: Try to setting DB_PORT=33060

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I made a mishap in the configuration. I didn't set the .env file config DB_PORT to 33060 as mentioned in the https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/homestead.